# Всплывающие подсказки с data-hint

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день, столкнулся с HTML в рамках лабораторной работы, более легкие задания удалось выполнить, а здесь не понимаю, как связать нестандартный атрибут input с другим элементом. Вообще, создавать всплывающие подсказки удается, но как как связать с определенными input ума не приложу.

Подсказки для полей ввода. Дана html-форма, содержащая поля ввода (input с типом
text), необходимо после загрузки странички добавить после полей, у которых имеется нестрандартный атрибут data-hint, новый элемент со знаком «?» при наведении на который над ним появляется подсказка взятая из нестандартного атрибута data-hint текущего поля ввода.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>JS-1</title>
    <link href = "hint.css-2.5.0/hint.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
  </head>

  <body>
   <p>Введите текст:</p>
    <input type = "text" size = "50">
    <span class="hint  hint--right  hint--info" data-hint="О, это подсказка">Наведи на меня</span>



    <form id = "form">
      <p>Форма:</p>
      <input type = "text" size = "50">

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос, что должно получится в итоге?

Comment: @l2banners Добрый день. Вот само задание: Подсказки для полей ввода. Дана html-форма, содержащая поля ввода (input с типом
text), необходимо после загрузки странички добавить после полей, у которых имеется нестрандартный атрибут data-hint, новый элемент со знаком «?» при наведении на который над ним появляется подсказка взятая из нестандартного атрибута data-hint
текущего поля ввода.

Впервые столкнулся с HTML, поэтому сам не особо сильно понимаю, чего нужно добиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/* Находим все input  */
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');

/* Проходим циклом по все найденым input*/
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  /*  Если input содержит атрибут data-hint выполнем код внутри if  */
  if ( input[i].getAttribute("data-hint") != null) {
        /*  Создаем контейнер span  */
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        /* Присваиваем созданному span класс  */
    span.className = "hint  hint--right  hint--info";
        /* Присваиваем созданному span содержимое  */
    span.innerHTML = "?";
        /* Вставляем в span атрибут data-hint и присваиваем значение из найденного input */
        span.setAttribute("data-hint", input[i].getAttribute("data-hint"));
    insertAfter(span, input[i]);
   } 
  }

/* Функция вставляет elementInstertAfter после parentElement  */
function insertAfter(elementInstertAfter, parentElement) {
 return parentElement.parentNode.insertBefore(elementInstertAfter, parentElement.nextSibling);
}
```

```css
/*! Hint.css - v2.3.0 - 2016-05-21
* http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/
* Copyright (c) 2016 Kushagra Gour; Licensed  */

[class*=hint--]{position:relative;display:inline-block}[class*=hint--]:after,[class*=hint--]:before{position:absolute;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0);visibility:hidden;opacity:0;z-index:1000000;pointer-events:none;-webkit-transition:.3s ease;-moz-transition:.3s ease;transition:.3s ease;-webkit-transition-delay:0ms;-moz-transition-delay:0ms;transition-delay:0ms}[class*=hint--]:hover:after,[class*=hint--]:hover:before{visibility:visible;opacity:1;-webkit-transition-delay:100ms;-moz-transition-delay:100ms;transition-delay:100ms}[class*=hint--]:before{content:'';position:absolute;background:0 0;border:6px solid transparent;z-index:1000001}[class*=hint--]:after{background:#383838;color:#fff;padding:8px 10px;font-size:12px;font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:12px;white-space:nowrap;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #000;box-shadow:4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3)}[class*=hint--][aria-label]:after{content:attr(aria-label)}[class*=hint--][data-hint]:after{content:attr(data-hint)}[aria-label='']:after,[aria-label='']:before,[data-hint='']:after,[data-hint='']:before{display:none!important}.hint--top-left:before,.hint--top-right:before,.hint--top:before{border-top-color:#383838}.hint--bottom-left:before,.hint--bottom-right:before,.hint--bottom:before{border-bottom-color:#383838}.hint--top:after,.hint--top:before{bottom:100%;left:50%}.hint--top:before{margin-bottom:-11px;left:calc(50% - 6px)}.hint--top:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);-moz-transform:translateX(-50%);transform:translateX(-50%)}.hint--top:focus:before,.hint--top:hover:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateY(-8px);transform:translateY(-8px)}.hint--top:focus:after,.hint--top:hover:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-8px);transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-8px)}.hint--bottom:after,.hint--bottom:before{top:100%;left:50%}.hint--bottom:before{margin-top:-11px;left:calc(50% - 6px)}.hint--bottom:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);-moz-transform:translateX(-50%);transform:translateX(-50%)}.hint--bottom:focus:before,.hint--bottom:hover:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateY(8px);transform:translateY(8px)}.hint--bottom:focus:after,.hint--bottom:hover:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(8px);transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(8px)}.hint--right:before{border-right-color:#383838;margin-left:-11px;margin-bottom:-6px}.hint--right:after{margin-bottom:-14px}.hint--right:after,.hint--right:before{left:100%;bottom:50%}.hint--right:focus:after,.hint--right:focus:before,.hint--right:hover:after,.hint--right:hover:before{-webkit-transform:translateX(8px);-moz-transform:translateX(8px);transform:translateX(8px)}.hint--left:before{border-left-color:#383838;margin-right:-11px;margin-bottom:-6px}.hint--left:after{margin-bottom:-14px}.hint--left:after,.hint--left:before{right:100%;bottom:50%}.hint--left:focus:after,.hint--left:focus:before,.hint--left:hover:after,.hint--left:hover:before{-webkit-transform:translateX(-8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-8px);transform:translateX(-8px)}.hint--top-left:after,.hint--top-left:before{bottom:100%;left:50%}.hint--top-left:before{margin-bottom:-11px;left:calc(50% - 6px)}.hint--top-left:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);-moz-transform:translateX(-100%);transform:translateX(-100%);margin-left:12px}.hint--top-left:focus:before,.hint--top-left:hover:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateY(-8px);transform:translateY(-8px)}.hint--top-left:focus:after,.hint--top-left:hover:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-8px);transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-8px)}.hint--top-right:after,.hint--top-right:before{bottom:100%;left:50%}.hint--top-right:before{margin-bottom:-11px;left:calc(50% - 6px)}.hint--top-right:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0);margin-left:-12px}.hint--top-right:focus:after,.hint--top-right:focus:before,.hint--top-right:hover:after,.hint--top-right:hover:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateY(-8px);transform:translateY(-8px)}.hint--bottom-left:after,.hint--bottom-left:before{top:100%;left:50%}.hint--bottom-left:before{margin-top:-11px;left:calc(50% - 6px)}.hint--bottom-left:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);-moz-transform:translateX(-100%);transform:translateX(-100%);margin-left:12px}.hint--bottom-left:focus:before,.hint--bottom-left:hover:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateY(8px);transform:translateY(8px)}.hint--bottom-left:focus:after,.hint--bottom-left:hover:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(8px);transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(8px)}.hint--bottom-right:after,.hint--bottom-right:before{top:100%;left:50%}.hint--bottom-right:before{margin-top:-11px;left:calc(50% - 6px)}.hint--bottom-right:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);-moz-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0);margin-left:-12px}.hint--bottom-right:focus:after,.hint--bottom-right:focus:before,.hint--bottom-right:hover:after,.hint--bottom-right:hover:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateY(8px);transform:translateY(8px)}.hint--large:after,.hint--medium:after,.hint--small:after{white-space:normal;line-height:1.4em}.hint--small:after{width:80px}.hint--medium:after{width:150px}.hint--large:after{width:300px}.hint--error:after{background-color:#b34e4d;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #592726}.hint--error.hint--top-left:before,.hint--error.hint--top-right:before,.hint--error.hint--top:before{border-top-color:#b34e4d}.hint--error.hint--bottom-left:before,.hint--error.hint--bottom-right:before,.hint--error.hint--bottom:before{border-bottom-color:#b34e4d}.hint--error.hint--left:before{border-left-color:#b34e4d}.hint--error.hint--right:before{border-right-color:#b34e4d}.hint--warning:after{background-color:#c09854;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #6c5328}.hint--warning.hint--top-left:before,.hint--warning.hint--top-right:before,.hint--warning.hint--top:before{border-top-color:#c09854}.hint--warning.hint--bottom-left:before,.hint--warning.hint--bottom-right:before,.hint--warning.hint--bottom:before{border-bottom-color:#c09854}.hint--warning.hint--left:before{border-left-color:#c09854}.hint--warning.hint--right:before{border-right-color:#c09854}.hint--info:after{background-color:#3986ac;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #1a3c4d}.hint--info.hint--top-left:before,.hint--info.hint--top-right:before,.hint--info.hint--top:before{border-top-color:#3986ac}.hint--info.hint--bottom-left:before,.hint--info.hint--bottom-right:before,.hint--info.hint--bottom:before{border-bottom-color:#3986ac}.hint--info.hint--left:before{border-left-color:#3986ac}.hint--info.hint--right:before{border-right-color:#3986ac}.hint--success:after{background-color:#458746;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #1a321a}.hint--success.hint--top-left:before,.hint--success.hint--top-right:before,.hint--success.hint--top:before{border-top-color:#458746}.hint--success.hint--bottom-left:before,.hint--success.hint--bottom-right:before,.hint--success.hint--bottom:before{border-bottom-color:#458746}.hint--success.hint--left:before{border-left-color:#458746}.hint--success.hint--right:before{border-right-color:#458746}.hint--always:after,.hint--always:before{opacity:1;visibility:visible}.hint--always.hint--top:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateY(-8px);transform:translateY(-8px)}.hint--always.hint--top:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-8px);transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-8px)}.hint--always.hint--top-left:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateY(-8px);transform:translateY(-8px)}.hint--always.hint--top-left:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-8px);transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-8px)}.hint--always.hint--top-right:after,.hint--always.hint--top-right:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateY(-8px);transform:translateY(-8px)}.hint--always.hint--bottom:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateY(8px);transform:translateY(8px)}.hint--always.hint--bottom:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(8px);transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(8px)}.hint--always.hint--bottom-left:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateY(8px);transform:translateY(8px)}.hint--always.hint--bottom-left:after{-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(8px);transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(8px)}.hint--always.hint--bottom-right:after,.hint--always.hint--bottom-right:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateY(8px);transform:translateY(8px)}.hint--always.hint--left:after,.hint--always.hint--left:before{-webkit-transform:translateX(-8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-8px);transform:translateX(-8px)}.hint--always.hint--right:after,.hint--always.hint--right:before{-webkit-transform:translateX(8px);-moz-transform:translateX(8px);transform:translateX(8px)}.hint--rounded:after{border-radius:4px}.hint--no-animate:after,.hint--no-animate:before{-webkit-transition-duration:0ms;-moz-transition-duration:0ms;transition-duration:0ms}.hint--bounce:after,.hint--bounce:before{-webkit-transition:opacity .3s ease,visibility .3s ease,-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.71,1.7,.77,1.24);-moz-transition:opacity .3s ease,visibility .3s ease,-moz-transform .3s cubic-bezier(.71,1.7,.77,1.24);transition:opacity .3s ease,visibility .3s ease,transform .3s cubic-bezier(.71,1.7,.77,1.24)}
```

```html
<form id="form">

    <p>Введите текст:</p>
    <input type="text" size="50" data-hint="О, это подсказка">

    <p>Форма:</p>
    <input type="text" size="50">

    <p>Введите текст 2:</p>
    <input type="text" size="50" data-hint="О, это вторая подсказка">


  </form>
```

Comment: @l3banners, огромное спасибо, это именно то, что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто нужно подключить сам файл библиотеки вот где её можно скачать [ссыка для скачвания](https://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>JS-1</title>

    <link href = "https://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/hint.min.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
  </head>

  <body>
   <p>Введите текст:</p>
    <input type = "text" size = "50">
    <span class="hint  hint--right  hint--info" data-hint="О, это подсказка">?</span>



    <form id = "form">
      <p>Форма:</p>
      <input type = "text" size = "50">
Hello Sir, <span class="hint hint--bottom" aria-label="Thank you!">hover over me.</span>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: добрый вечер, спасибо, но подсказки у меня отображались, но за дополнительную информацию благодарю. Я отредактировал суть проблемы, добавил описание. Если сможете оказать какую-то помощь, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @AndreyCOYG спрашивай

Comment: @AndreyCOYG так поставь "?"