# Как указать место для вывода hint в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

В HTML странице есть две таблицы (Т1 и Т2) одна над другой.
Каждая ячейка содержит ссылку и скрытый текст для вывода. т.е. нажимая на ячейку, над таблицей выводится текст, который соответствует этой ячейке.
В данный момент скрипт написан так, что независимо от того, в какой таблице кликаем по ячейке информация всегда появляется над первой таблицей, а надо чтобы информация выводилась над той таблицей в которой кликаем по ячейке.

Содержание таблицы 1 (пример):

```
<div id="hint" onClick="this.style.display='none'"></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <span data-hint="Связь 11 - 11" onClick="hint(this,event)">t1_11_11</span> 
    </td>
    <td>
       <span data-hint="Связь 5 - 7" onClick="hint(this,event)">t1_5_7b</span> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Содержание таблицы 2 (пример):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <span data-hint="Связь 3 - 15" onClick="hint(this,event)">t2_3_15</span> 
    </td>
    <td>
       <span data-hint="Связь 2 - 8" onClick="hint(this,event)">t2_2_8b</span> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Скрипт выглядит так:

```
        <script>
            function hint(obj,event) {
              h = document.getElementById('hint'); 
              h.innerHTML = obj.dataset.hint; 
              h.style.left = event.pageX; 
              h.style.top = event.pageY+10; 
              h.style.display = 'block'; 
            } 
        </script>;
```

Что и где надо добавить, чтобы результаты выводились над разными ячейками?

Comment: добавьте структуру таблицы и эл-та с `id="hint"`

Comment: Можно заменить `h = document.getElementById('hint'); ` на `h =  obj.closest('table').previousElementSibling`

Comment: Да, все сработало, спасибо!!!

Comment: `h.style.position = 'absolute'` - переключить на абсолютная позиция относительно начала координат. А уже абсолютную позицию можно узнать вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759867/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-html-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0

Comment: Вариант 2 переключить на `h.style.position = 'relative'` относительную позицию. Тогда через offsetX и константу можно подобрать формулу и елемент будет на желаемом месте.

Comment: Возможно вам подойдёт это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758843/%d0%92%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-data-hint/758875#758875

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предлагаю завязаться через абсолютную адресацию. Т.е. получить позицию относительно вернего левого угла, и от неё всё описать. Например так

```
h = document.getElementById('hint'); 
h.style.position= "absolute";
h.style.display = "block";
h.style.top=(getOffset(event.target||event.srcElement).top-1)+"px"; 
h.style.left=(getOffset(event.target||event.srcElement).left-2)+"px";
```

Где 1 и 2  - подберете константы.

Ф-ция

```
function getOffset(elem) {
    if (elem.getBoundingClientRect) {
    var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    var body = document.body;
    var docElem = document.documentElement;
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
    var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;
    var clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
    var clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;
    return { top: Math.round(box.top +  scrollTop - clientTop), left: Math.round(box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft) }      
    } else {
         var top=0, left=0
    while(elem) {
        top = top + parseFloat(elem.offsetTop);
        left = left + parseFloat(elem.offsetLeft);
        elem = elem.offsetParent ;
       }
       return {top: top, left: left};
       }
}
```

Ф-ция позицировния [getOffset](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759867/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-html-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Так же рекомендую посмотреть этот пример [Всплывающие подсказки с data-hint](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758843/%d0%92%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-data-hint/758875#758875)

Answer (score 2):

оставлю тут для будущих пользователей, у которых возникнет подобный вопрос, просто ещё один вариант реализации подсказок (простой, без проверки на видимость).

[codepen](https://codepen.io/meine54/full/XvMPBZ)

```js
class Hint {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.onHover = this.onHover.bind(this);
    this.onLeave = this.onLeave.bind(this);

    this.node.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.onHover, false);
    this.node.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.onLeave, false);
  }

  onHover() {
    const text = this.getText();
    const type = this.getType();

    this._createHint(text, type);
  }

  onLeave() {
    document.querySelector('.hint').remove();
  }

  getText() {
    return this.node.getAttribute('data-hint');
  }

  getType() {
    return this.node.getAttribute('data-type');
  }

  _createHint(text, type) {
    const content = `
      <div class="hint__container">
        <div class="hint__text">${text}</div>
      </div>
    `

    const hintWnd = this._createWindow(type);

    hintWnd.innerHTML = content;

    this.node.appendChild(hintWnd);
  }

  _createWindow(type) {
    const typeClass = this._getTypeClass(type);

    const hintNode = document.createElement('div');

    hintNode.classList.add('hint', typeClass);

    return hintNode;
  }

  _getTypeClass(type) {
    // created for relief html, can be delete
    switch (type) {
      case 'important':
        return 'hint_type_important';
        break;
      default:
        return 'hint_type_default';
    }
  }
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-widget="hint"]')]
.forEach(hint => new Hint(hint));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.block__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -15px;
}

.block__item {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 33.333333333%;
  height: 176.66px;
}

.block__content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  position: relative;
}

.block__content:hover,
.block__content:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

.hint {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  animation: scaled .3s forwards;
  top: -50px;
  left: 20px;
}

.hint_type_important {
  color: #FF6F61;
}

.hint_type_default {
  color: #838383;
}

@keyframes scaled {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__container">
    <div class="block__item">
      <div class="block__content" data-widget="hint" data-hint="Hint #1" data-type="important"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block__item">
      <div class="block__content" data-widget="hint" data-hint="Hint #2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block__item">
      <div class="block__content" data-widget="hint" data-hint="Hint #3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block__item">
      <div class="block__content" data-widget="hint" data-hint="Hint #4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block__item">
      <div class="block__content" data-widget="hint" data-hint="Hint #5"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block__item">
      <div class="block__content" data-widget="hint" data-hint="Hint #6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```